# Is Header required in a message?

Tags: custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/msg states:

> The special nature of Header is mainly for historical reasons, such as preserving recorded data.

Does this mean that for newly created messages this field should/must omitted? Or should I still include it (to have normal/full functionality)?

I guess my question actually is: What is this Header type and why do I need it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134361/is-header-required-in-a-message?/) by [veger](https://answers.ros.org/users/11971/veger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: Include a Header in your message iff you need a header.

Longer answer: Header contains standardized information like a time stamp and frame id for TF. If your messages is of a nature that requires such things, it is good practice to use the standard Header instead of producing such things by yourself. If your message does not need such information, you don't need a header.

The special nature is that ROS classes might handle a message with header slightly different. There is the old seq id that is automatically incremented by publishers. In all other cases publishers do publish exactly the message you give them.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2